# Why Should I Use The TextMate MissingDrawer Plugin?

Tags: plugins, textmate

I'm considering installing Jannis Leidel's [MissingDrawer](https://github.com/jezdez/textmate-missingdrawer) TextMate plugin. Here is a description from the plugin's README.

> This plugin provides Xcode-like project window interface without drawer and adds "Open Terminal Here" button to the file list's button panel.

From experience, what advantages does the "Xcode-like project window interface" provide over TextMate's built-in Project Draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, it's just cosmetic.

I've disliked the look and behaviour of Mac OS X's drawer since the beginning (Mac OS X 10.3 for me) and I was relieved when someone created this plugin.

There was [another project](http://ciaranwal.sh/projectplus) with a similar goal but more interesting features like SCM badges. This is the one I used and I'd recommend.